# How to open and save a file in gtk?

Tags: c, gtk

i am new to gtk. I am trying to make a simple text editor. I am using codeblocks as my ide.

After looking at the documentation for opening and saving at https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html, the code snippet shown has used a function called open_file(filename). The compiler throws an error that the open_file() is undeclared.

Can someone please help me with the implementation of this function?

Comment: Can you show what command you used to compile?  Have you link the necessary libraries?

Comment: By the way, i am using a windows 8. so i didnt use the command prompt to compile. i have included #include <gtk/gtk.h>

Comment: `open_file()` is not part of the standard or `glib`, after `filename = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename (chooser);` use `FILE *f = fopen(filename);`

Comment: In those examples `open_file` and `save_to_file` are most certainly placeholders for real (platform dependent) code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, right now the open dialog works. So when i select a file from the dialog, the f points to the file, right? To display the selected file in the text view, should i move it to the buffer first? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 6):

That code is just an example. `open_file()` in that case is provided by you. GTK+ has no file manipulation functions. [GLib, which GTK+ is built on, does have](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-File-Utilities.html) [file manipulation functions you can use](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/file_ops.html), but you don't have to use them — you can use any other file manipulation API at your disposal.